# TinyMCE & MoxieManager: url from MoxieManager won't be passed to TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce, mcimagemanager

I'm running TinyMCE 4.0b in combination with MoxieManager 1.3.3.

When I use the 'Insert File'-button in TinyMCE which opens Moxiemanager directly, I will succeed inserting an image.
When I use the 'Link' / 'Image' / 'Media' dialog box I'm selecting the right image in MoxieManager, the api.php-response shows the right image url, but in the TinyMCE dialog box the url of the current page is visible (instead of the image url!)

I've already tried to change the rootpath, path, file_ and image_template, relative_urls, but nothing seems to help.
Is there anyone who have an idea why TinyMCE couldn't receive the right image url?

URL path as received from MoxieManager API:
[image: URL path as received from MoxieManager API]

URL path in image / file dialog box
[image: URL path in image / file dialog box]

Initialisation code:

```
tinymce.init({
height                  : 380,
width                   : '100%',

mode                    : "textareas",
editor_selector         : "mceEditor",
language                : "nl",
invalid_elements        : "textarea",

fix_list_elements       : true,

remove_script_host      : true,
media_use_script        : true,
entity_encoding         : "numeric",
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste     : true,

skin                    : 'bp',
menubar                 : false,
statusbar               : false,

image_advtab            :true,

plugins                 : "moxiemanager,advlist,autolink,lists,link,textcolor,image,charmap,print,preview,anchor,searchreplace,visualblocks,code,fullscreen,insertdatetime,media,table,wordcount,contextmenu,paste,autosave,colorpicker",

relative_urls           : false,
toolbar                 : "insertfile image media | formatselect styleselect | bold italic underline forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | paste searchreplace | bullist numlist | removeformat hr charmap | link unlink anchor | fullscreen code table",

contextmenu             : "link image inserttable | cell row column tableprops deletetable",

link_list               :   window.location.protocol + '//'+location.hostname+'/javascript/tinymce4/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/link/myexternallist.php',

moxiemanager_image_settings :   {
                                    view: 'thumbs',
                                    path: '/gfx',
                                    exclude_directory_pattern: '/^(mcith|.svn|export)$/i',
                                    title: 'Image management',
                                    extensions: 'jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG'
                                },
moxiemanager_file_settings  :   {
                                    view: 'files',
                                    path: '',
                                    exclude_directory_pattern: '/^(mcith|.svn|gfx|export)$/i',
                                    title: 'File Management',
                                    extensions: 'swf,SWF,pdf,PDF,doc,DOC,docx,DOCX,zip,ZIP,xls,XLS,xlsx,XLSX,csv,CSV,avi,AVI,mov,MOV,mp4,MP4,flv,FLV,m4v,M4V'
                                },
moxiemanager_media_settings :   {
                                    view: 'files',
                                    path: '/media',
                                    exclude_directory_pattern: '/^(mcith|.svn|gfx|export)$/i',
                                    title: 'Media Management',
                                    extensions: 'swf,SWF,avi,AVI,mov,MOV,mp4,MP4,flv,FLV,m4v,M4V'
                                },
//moxiemanager_view         :   'thumbs',
moxiemanager_leftpanel      :   false,
moxiemanager_image_template :   '<img src="https://url.ext/user/{$path}" width="{$meta.width}" height="{$meta.height}" />',
moxiemanager_file_template  :   '<a href="https://url.ext/user/<?= $site['name']; ?>{$path}" target="_blank">{$name}</a>',
moxiemanager_user           :   '<?= $_SESSION['username'] ?>', 

style_formats       : [
    { title : 'Paragraph', block : 'p', classes : '', styles : { } },
    { title : 'Header 1', block : 'h1', classes : '', styles : { } },
    { title : 'Header 2', block : 'h2', classes : '', styles : { } },
    { title : 'Header 3', block : 'h3', classes : '', styles : { } },
    { title : 'Header 4', block : 'h4', classes : '', styles : { } },
    { title : 'Header 5', block : 'h5', classes : '', styles : { } },
    { title : 'Header 6', block : 'h6', classes : '', styles : { } },
]
});
```

And the Moxiemanager configuration:

```
<?php
//includes de config om toegang te verkrijgen tot de SESSION. Dit is nodig omdat hier bepaald moet worden wat de username is van de gebruiker om zo het rootpath aan te wijzen.
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/init.php');

$langUrl = JAVASCRIPT. 'tinymce4/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/moxiemanager/langs/moxman_nl_NL.js';
$sUsername = $_SESSION['username'];
//     if ($sUsername == '' || $sUsername == 'undefined') die('ERROR: Attempted to load the moxiemanager without being logged into app, this should never happen.');

// General
$moxieManagerConfig['general.license']          =   'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX';
$moxieManagerConfig['general.hidden_tools']     =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['general.disabled_tools']   =   '';
//$moxieManagerConfig['general.plugins']            =   'History,Uploaded,Quota';
$moxieManagerConfig['general.plugins']          =   'History,Uploaded';
$moxieManagerConfig['general.demo']             =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['general.debug']            =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['general.language']         =   'nl_NL';
$moxieManagerConfig['general.temp_dir']         =   "https://url.ext/user/moxietmp"; 
$moxieManagerConfig['general.allow_override']   =   'hidden_tools,disabled_tools';

// !!dit stuk in de config is nodig, ook al set de 'browse' functie deze dmv setFileManager in main.js, die functie wordt aangeroepen in afbeeldingenList.php en downloadsList.php
// (let op, NIET tinyMce.php met de 'bestand invoegen' knoppen)

// Filesystem
//lib.js writes a cookie containing the latest window.location. We use this as a workaround to the fact that the relevant data from $_REQUEST['URI'] is not available in an ajax request in
//this context and $_REQUEST['HTTP_REFERER] is not reliable in older versions of IE
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.rootpath']                      =   "https://url.ext/user/".$sUsername."/";

$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.include_directory_pattern']     =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.exclude_directory_pattern']     =   '/^(.svn|export)$/i';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.include_file_pattern']          =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.exclude_file_pattern']          =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.extensions']                    =   'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,html,txt,docx,doc,zip,pdf,xls,xlsx,csv,avi,mov,mp4,flv,m4v';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.readable']                      =   true;
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.writable']                      =   true;
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.allow_override']                =   '*';

// Createdir
$moxieManagerConfig['createdir.templates']                      =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdir.include_directory_pattern']      =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdir.exclude_directory_pattern']      =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdir.allow_override']                 =   '*';

// Createdoc
$moxieManagerConfig['createdoc.templates']                      =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdoc.fields']                         =   'Document title=title';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdoc.include_file_pattern']           =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdoc.exclude_file_pattern']           =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdoc.extensions']                     =   '*';
$moxieManagerConfig['createdoc.allow_override']                 =   '*';

// Upload
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.include_file_pattern']              =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.exclude_file_pattern']              =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.extensions']                        =   '*';
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.maxsize']                           =   '100MB';
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.overwrite']                         =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.autoresize']                        =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.autoresize_jpeg_quality']           =   90;
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.max_width']                         =   800;
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.max_height']                        =   600;
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.chunk_size']                        =   '5mb';
$moxieManagerConfig['upload.allow_override']                    =   '*';

// Rename
$moxieManagerConfig['rename.include_file_pattern']              =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['rename.exclude_file_pattern']              =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['rename.include_directory_pattern']         =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['rename.exclude_directory_pattern']         =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['rename.extensions']                        =   '*';
$moxieManagerConfig['rename.allow_override']                    =   '*';

// Edit
$moxieManagerConfig['edit.include_file_pattern']                =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['edit.exclude_file_pattern']                =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['edit.extensions']                          =   'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,html,htm,txt';
$moxieManagerConfig['edit.jpeg_quality']                        =   90;
$moxieManagerConfig['edit.allow_override']                      =   '*';

// View
$moxieManagerConfig['view.include_file_pattern']                =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['view.exclude_file_pattern']                =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['view.extensions']                          =   'jpg,jpeg,png,gif,html,htm,txt,pdf';
$moxieManagerConfig['view.allow_override']                      =   '*';

// Download
$moxieManagerConfig['download.include_file_pattern']            =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['download.exclude_file_pattern']            =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['download.extensions']                      =   '*';
$moxieManagerConfig['download.allow_override']                  =   '*';

// Thumbnail
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.enabled']                        =   true;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.auto_generate']                  =   true;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.use_exif']                       =   true;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.width']                          =   90;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.height']                         =   90;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.mode']                           =   "resize";
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.folder']                         =   'mcith';
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.prefix']                         =   'mcith_';
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.delete']                         =   true;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.jpeg_quality']                   =   75;
$moxieManagerConfig['thumbnail.allow_override']                 =   '*';

// Authentication
$moxieManagerConfig['authenticator']                            =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['authenticator.login_page']                 =   '';


// IpAuthenticator
$moxieManagerConfig['IpAuthenticator.ip_numbers']               =   '127.0.0.1';

// ExternalAuthenticator
$moxieManagerConfig['ExternalAuthenticator.external_auth_url']  =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['ExternalAuthenticator.secret_key']         =   '';

// Local filesystem
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.wwwroot']                 =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.urlprefix']               =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.urlsuffix']               =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.access_file_name']        =   'mc_access';
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.cache']                   =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.allow_override']          =   '*';

// Log
$moxieManagerConfig['log.enabled']                              =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['log.level']                                =   'error';
$moxieManagerConfig['log.path']                                 =   'data/logs';
$moxieManagerConfig['log.filename']                             =   '{level}.log';
$moxieManagerConfig['log.format']                               =   '[{time}] [{level}] {message}';
$moxieManagerConfig['log.max_size']                             =   '100k';
$moxieManagerConfig['log.max_files']                            =   '10';
$moxieManagerConfig['log.filter']                               =   '';

// Cache
$moxieManagerConfig['cache.connection']                         =   "sqlite:./data/storage/cache.s3db";

// Storage
$moxieManagerConfig['storage.engine']                           =   'json';
$moxieManagerConfig['storage.path']                             =   './data/storage';

// AutoFormat plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['autoformat.rules']                         =   '';
$moxieManagerConfig['autoformat.jpeg_quality']                  =   90;
$moxieManagerConfig['autoformat.delete_format_images']          =   true;

// AutoRename, remember to include it in your plugin config.
$moxieManagerConfig['autorename.enabled']                       =   false;
$moxieManagerConfig['autorename.spacechar']                     =   "_";
$moxieManagerConfig['autorename.lowercase']                     =   false;

// BasicAuthenticator plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['basicauthenticator.users']                 =   array(
                                                                        array("username" => "xxx", "password" => "xxxx", "groups" => array("administrator"))
                                                                    );

// GoogleDrive
$moxieManagerConfig['googledrive.client_id']                    =   '';

// DropBox
$moxieManagerConfig['dropbox.app_id']                           =   '';

// Amazon S3 plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['amazons3.buckets']                         =   array(
                                                                    'bucketname' =>     
                                                                        array(
                                                                            'publickey' => '',
                                                                            'secretkey' => ''
                                                                        )
                                                                    );

// Ftp plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['ftp.accounts']                             =   array(
                                                                    'ftpname' => 
                                                                        array(
                                                                            'host' => '',
                                                                            'user' => '',
                                                                            'password' => '',
                                                                            'rootpath' => '/',
                                                                            'wwwroot' => '/',
                                                                            'passive' => true
                                                                        )
                                                                    );

// Favorites plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['favorites.max']                            =   0;

// History plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['history.max']                              =   0;

// Quota plugin
$moxieManagerConfig['quota.max_size']                           =   ( is_numeric( $_SESSION['moxManQuota'] ) ) ? $_SESSION['moxManQuota']."m" : "10m";
?>
```

Comment: The problem seemed to be an out-dated version of Moxiemanager. With the new release the problem has been solved...

Answer (score 2):

This is a really late answer, but defining the right `wwwroot` setting was enough to fix it. My working parameter is pointing to my web root and looking like `$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.local.wwwroot'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../..');`.